# How to use vim command character to find an explain in it's help file

Tags: vim

I try some vim command, and find the `gh` command will start a new command mode, which shows `--select--` in my screan. just like the `--visual--` command mode, that this `--select--` mode can select some text.

I want know more about this command mode, then I press <kbd>F1</kbd> to show the vim help file in vi.

how can I find the `gh` command in this help file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to find help for a command in Vim, use the command mode (the one where you type `:wq` for exiting):

```
:help gh
```

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to show a list of possible completions after typing this,

```
:he gh
gh                               c_<Right>                        -menuheight                      zip-copyright                    match-highlight                  Vimball-copyright
ghc                              i_<Right>                        :belowright                      'cmdwinheight'                   netrw-copyright                  <ScrollWheelRight>
'ghr'                            c_<C-Right>                      'helpheight'                     'nosplitright'                   'nowinfixheight'                 <C-ScrollWheelRight>
g:ghc                            c_<S-Right>                      'splitright'                     'winfixheight'                   shift-left-right                 <S-ScrollWheelRight>
```

As you can see, `gh` is listed, so just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
                                                        gh
gh                      Start Select mode, characterwise.  This is like "v",
                        but starts Select mode instead of Visual mode.
                        Mnemonic: "get highlighted".
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:h select-mode` and you see the description of the select mode. Here an excerpt:

```
==============================================================================
8. Select mode                                          *Select* *Select-mode*

Select mode looks like Visual mode, but the commands accepted are quite
different.  This resembles the selection mode in Microsoft Windows.
When the 'showmode' option is set, "-- SELECT --" is shown in the last line.

Entering Select mode:
- Using the mouse to select an area, and 'selectmode' contains "mouse".
  'mouse' must also contain a flag for the current mode.
- Using a non-printable movement command, with the Shift key pressed, and
  'selectmode' contains "key".  For example: <S-Left> and <S-End>.  'keymodel'
  must also contain "startsel".
- Using "v", "V" or CTRL-V command, and 'selectmode' contains "cmd".
- Using "gh", "gH" or "g_CTRL-H" command in Normal mode.
- From Visual mode, press CTRL-G.                       *v_CTRL-G*

...
                                                        *gh*

gh                      Start Select mode, characterwise.  This is like "v",
                        but starts Select mode instead of Visual mode.
                        Mnemonic: "get highlighted".
...
```